# I found an unusual (at least for me) answer in Wolfram Alpha I don't understand

Tags: roots, wolfram-alpha

Sorry in advance, is my first question and i found something weird in wolfram

The problem:

Given a function f, and a chain of links with lengths (h0, h1, h2...), calculate the points where every chain links end following the f function, starting in (0,0).

In this case 
  [image: f-function]. Take only the range [0, a)

Graphically this question is trivial:

[image] 
an so on... Every crossing point is the center of the next circle with radius hn.

The question here is: solve it using algebra/calculus.

The result equation is easy too: [image: circle equation cross f function] where w is x of the previous iteration (in first iteration is 0)

Now, I want to take and clear x, and wolfram comes and says to me
[image: wolfram error]

Are that symbols maths beyond my knowledge (is possible) or I broke wolfram alpha?

Exists an easiest solution to this problem I'm not seeing?

Comment: The equation is not easy, as it is equivalent to a sextic polynomial. Hence there is no analytical solution.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Then the answer to this problem is "there is not analytical solution to this problem"? Because I'm going mad trying to found something

Comment: Polynomials of degree 5 or higher have no general formula in radicals. Maybe it comes from that?

Comment: The Root in `Root[ ... &, 1]` is WA's root finder.
The first argument `.... &` ended with `&` indicate it is a pure function (also known as an anonymous function), WA uses the `#1`, `#2`, ... to indicate the arguments to this pure function. e.g. `Root [ #1^2 + #1 + w &, 1 ]` means the 1st root for $x$ of the quadratic polynomial $x^2 + x + w = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you did not break WolframAlpha. You asked it to solve a problem that led to a $6$<sup>th</sup> degree polynomial equation and it tried to find its roots. But it found no closed formula for them. That's its way of talking about those roots. You will find more about it [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html).

Comment: And what means that "fancy pads" I never seen before?

Comment: Related: Abel-Ruffini Theorem

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about. Does it have to do with the $\#$ symbol?